# Why can't I use "their" here?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

I often see sentences like

> We are interested in predicting whether an individual will default on his or her credit 
>       card
>   or
>
> Activate only when your opponent adds a card to his or her hand

Why are people using "his or her"? Would it be correct to replace "his or her" with "their"? For example

> We are interested in predicting whether an individual will default on their credit card

This seems like it says the same as the first sentence, but I never see it used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a movement afoot (actually, the "movement" dates back many years, I suspect) to get rid of the awkward pairing of supposedly singular words such as someone, anyone, individual, person, ad infinitum with *he/she* or *his/her* and just go with *they* and *their*. Instead of

> If anyone wants to leave, he or she should feel free to do so,

just say

> If anyone wants to leave, they should feel free to do so.

Or, instead of

> Somebody made a mess in the kitchen, and he or she knows who he or she is,

just say

> Somebody made a mess in the kitchen, and they know who they are.

To be honest, I've had difficulty getting used the less awkward *their* paired with supposedly singular words, but I have been trying it lately, and no one on this site reprimanded me--at least thus far.

By the way, an interim technique of mine (and I suspect of some other weirdos) is to make the singular word *really* plural so that the pronoun replacing it has to be plural also. Instead of

> Every individual needing a pencil raised his or her hand,

I might use

> All those needing a pencil raised their hand.

Or, instead of

> Every person here is responsible for his or her own property,

I might use

> All people here are responsible for their own property.

Strict grammarians, at one time, may have been a little inflexible in this regard; loosey-goosey communicators nowadays, on the other hand, not so much. I say, "Go for it, user78655."

Oh, and anyone else so inclined, well, ***they*** too should go for it!

Comment: The movement succeeded with most English speakers several decades ago. And strict grammarians are indeed inflexible here; we believe that _he/she_ is hopelessly gauche. The correct pronoun, according to strict grammarians, is _their_. The people who think _he/she_ is cool are not grammarians, though they may indeed be strict. Grammarians know better.

Comment: The pairing of 'she' with 'their' is nonsensical. The modern practice pairs singular 'they' if needed with 'their'. 'She' and 'her' make a fixed pairing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Feel free to edit my answer as you see fit. Not being a grammarian, I am sometimes careless (ignorant?) in the way I word  all things grammatical. Perhaps I should have said "the third-person singular word, such as 'anyone'--i.e., he/she--paired with the third-person possessive plural," or some such thing. Again, feel free to edit. Thanks. Don

Comment: It has been answered before. 'Singular they' is the phrase to look up.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Does my latest edit make my answer at least somewhat more sensible? Just wonderin'. Don

Comment: It reads fine now. But it has been answered before on ELU.